# react native reloading is not working

Tags: react-native, websocket

### Description

When I fix my code and reloaded simulator,  nothing is changed.
This definitely not depends on my modified code.
I modified Text tag and reloaded simulator, nothing is changed too.

I seem to remember I did nothing yesterday and today, this was happened.
i tried to fix this, remove node_modules dir and reinstall ... but I couldn't

Here is the output from my console. 

`Error: not opened
    at WebSocket.send (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:219:16)
    at send (/app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/webSocketProxy.js:24:12)
    at WebSocket.debuggerSocket.onmessage (/app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/util/webSocketProxy.js:47:46)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:442:14)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Receiver.ontext (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at /app/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
    at /app/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:368:7
    at /app/node_modules/ws/lib/PerMessageDeflate.js:249:5
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:483:3)`

I accessed `http://localhost:8081/path/to/modify/code.js` and checked code was modified.
please fix this.

### Environment

- React Native version: "0.55.3"
- Platform: iOS
- Development Operating System: MacOS
- Dev tools: "X Code 9.3.1" iPhone6 simulator

### add info

I made a new react-native project with "react-native init" today.
I changed some text in App class and reloaded simulator, then modification place was appeared in simulator.

From the above I think something went wrong in my project.

but i did reset simulator(to press "Erase all Content and Setting"), erase source code and pull again, but not going well.

please give me another approaching.

Comment: try closing ur debugger. and try again

Comment: > try closing ur debugger. and try again
I stopped debugger, but still not work

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands

```
> npm install //to get the node module folder

> react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder

> react-native link // for linking the libraries

> react-native run ios/android
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question  

I did this step. but it  cause a problem `Native module cannot be null`  

I'm so sorry, this problem is occurred in taken over project.
I would rather not change as much as possible \n

I tried reinstall watchman and remove file related watchman, but still not good

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart android emulator using studio and also restrat `npm start`.. First do command then restart emulator...

Comment: thank you so much for answering my question
I'm so sorry. I 'm using ios simulator.
I restart ios simulator like this way, but still not work.